# Are the days and nights in Minecraft of equal length?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

It might just be subjective, but to me the nights seem to be longer than the days. Barely have I gone outside to collect some sand to make glass, or see if I can find that promising looking cave again when night falls.

Even with the watch to show me when it's nearly dawn there doesn't seem to be enough time.

Are there seasons in Minecraft and can I expect to have longer days at some point?

Comment: Re: seasons. They're coming but I don't think they'll affect day/night times.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

As it has been stated, **days are actually longer than nights.** Here, [have a diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE7VV.png) — yet you're not entirely wrong! There is a logical reason why days *do* feel shorter.

Day and night only matter on the surface, where it regulates mob spawning. At sunset, there's no mob on the surface. At sunrise, there is however. By the time the night's mob spawn is burned away by sunlight and it's safe to go out again, a sizable chunk of precious day time will have gone wasted.

If we mark with red the dangerous period of the day, with green the productive period of the day and with orange the risk transitions between, we get this:

[image: Days are 10 minutes long. Nights are 7 minutes long. Sunset and sunrise are 1 minute and a half each.]

So yes. While day is longer than night, *the productive period is actually shorter than the risky period.* In a way, yes: night and its practical effects are longer than day's.

This is connected to why properly lit mines are much safer and much more productive environments than surface is.

Answer (score 16):

#### Are the Nights longer than the days?

_

No. "Solar Days" are 20 minutes in total with Daytime lasting 10 minutes, night time lasting 7, with 1:30 for dawn / dusk.

Further detailed [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Day).

So relax -- it's all in your head. :)

Comment: Which is actually opposite to my subjective experience! It must be because I'm trying to get things done.

Comment: @ChrisF -- you can thank the psychological concept of "memory bias" for that. Humans tend to think that things they notice happen more frequently in the absence of other evidence.

Comment: @Raven - I thought it was purely psychological, but wanted to check.

Comment: @Raven - Isn't that confirmation bias, memory bias relating more to.. well, memory?

Comment: @Arda Xi -- It's probably a combination of both more than any one thing in particular. Both could or could not be affecting ChrisF. Psychology is wishy-washy like that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested it on my world using a timer and it shows that the **safe time lasts about 10 mins 30 seconds** between day and sunset, whereas **mobs spawn and are active for 9 mins 30 seconds** between night and sunrise. However, it takes 20 seconds for the mobs to burn after the day starts. This is set on Difficulty: Normal.

Answer (score -2):

No.The usual Minecraft day and night consists of 33 minutes. The day time takes up 20 minutes of that time. Therefore, nighttime only consists of 13 minutes. Which means that the Minecraft day is longer than the Minecraft night.

Comment: this doesn't add any info to a question that is 10 years old.

Comment: no, this is just wrong

Answer (score -4):

There is only 20 min. per day, and 7 min. at night, if you are unlucky, and don't have a bed, you have to find a way to survive the night away from all the mobs that spawn at night..

Comment: This adds nothing to the question, Raven Dreamer gave a similar answer almost 7 years ago.

Answer (score -4):

It all just depends on the mode that you are on (Ex. Peaceful, Easy, Normal or Hard) The days will get shorter, and the nights will get longer, depending on how far up the scale you go. On Peaceful, the nights and days will be at equal length, and when you change the difficulty, the days will become a little less than what the nights will become. Overall, a day in Minecraft lasts about 12 minutes, give or take a few.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this? This almost completely contradicts the other two answers.

Comment: All peaceful does is remove hostile mobs, making the "dawn" safer, and therefore making the day feel longer because you can safely go out earlier.