# How long is a redstone night?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am currently creating a debuff system that gives you slowness during the night if you don't use a bed.  I am using a daylight sensor and was wondering how long the effect should last.  I thought just a full night would be fine but now I need to know (in real time) how long a night is (Or more specifically how long a daylight sensor doesn't send out a redstone signal for).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are the days and nights in Minecraft of equal length?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10208/are-the-days-and-nights-in-minecraft-of-equal-length)

Comment: While somewhat tangential to the linked question, night length [is indeed covered](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/10209/5029).

Comment: @NovaSword After rereading it, I think the question is not a duplicate because the asker wants to know how long night is *from the perspective of a redstone circuit*, rather than the player's/skybox, which is what I was answering in that other question. The difference is that it's not clear how long the period is from transition to transition; I suppose it's somewhere between 7 minutes and 10, but I don't know just how long it is.

Comment: (Also, I'm afraid that answer might depend on torches or the weather if the circuit is triggered by light levels.)

Comment: @badp If he is asking about it from the perspective of a redstone circuit, then I agree it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

From [the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Day-night_cycle):

> #### Daytime
>
> ---
>
> Daytime is the longest section of the cycle, lasting 10 minutes in PC
> and 6 minutes in Pocket Edition.
>
> #### Sunset/dusk
>
> ---
>
> Lasts 1 1⁄2 minutes in PC and  9⁄10 of a minute in Pocket Edition.
>
> #### Nighttime
>
> ---
>
> Lasts 7 minutes in PC and 4 1⁄5 minutes in Pocket Edition.
>
> #### Sunrise/dawn
>
> ---
>
> Lasts 1 1⁄2 minutes in PC and  9⁄10 of a minute in Pocket Edition.

A light sensor should output 15 for ten minutes, go down to zero over 1.5 minutes, stay at zero for seven minutes, and go back up to 15 over 1.5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

A night in Minecraft is approximately 7 minutes in real life.